# Why don't apes other than Caesar speak English?

Tags: war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes

The accepted answer on the question ***[Other apes with gained intelligence?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23100/other-apes-with-gained-intelligence)*** says about **Maurice (Orangutan)**:

> This big ape did not gain intelligence from treatment but he knows sign language because he was in circus in the past.

In the movie [*War for the Planet of the Apes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_for_the_Planet_of_the_Apes) it's seen that all other apes are speaking in sign language to one another, considering they may have learned it from *Maurice*. While *Caesar* speaks to apes in English they seem to understand, but they reply in sign language.

*Caesar* speaks in English almost every time, he could have taught the other apes English other than sign language. The [*wiki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_for_the_Planet_of_the_Apes) says that the third movie takes place two years after the second one. Why didn't *Caesar* teach them English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the other apes do speak English from time to time, but not as much as Ceasar (Koba for example speaks very broken English in Dawn).

If you recall from other films, Ceasar speaks more and more over time. The virus that gave the apes enhanced intelligence has allowed them to evolve genetically and speech is part of that evolution, but it doesn't happen all at once but is developed over time.

Ceasar speaks more than the others for the same reason he is their leader. He was given enhanced intelligence earlier than the rest of the apes so has evolved futher than they have.